# CSS animation-delay doesn't apply to all elements

Tags: css, css-animations

As you can see i'm applying a delay to even and odd nth-of-type, but the problem is that the delay is always the same for both, no matter what. So if I put 10 seconds on odd and 3 seconds on even, it'll be 10 seconds for all a links.

```
a {
          position: relative;
          line-height: 200%;
          display: inline-block;
          text-transform: uppercase;
          font-size: $header-link-size;
          transform: scale(0);
          animation: scaleIn .5s;
          animation-fill-mode: both;

          &:nth-of-type(even) {
            animation-delay: 2s;
          }

          &:nth-of-type(odd) {
            animation-delay: 3s;
          }

          @keyframes scaleIn {
            from {
              transform: scale(0);
            }
            to {
              transform: scale(1);
            }
          }
}
```

Comment: CSS seems to work fine, could you provide your relevant HTML?

Comment: @Marvin, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ygoyQL, check the animation delay for the link and you'll see how it's still the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `nth-of-type()`-selector will match any element that is the nth child of a type inside the same parent element (we talk about ***siblings***). It won't work for nested elements. So regarding your markup every `<a>` inside of a `<li>` is the only one, thus it is always odd and the animation-delay is the same for all.

You have to select even and odd `<li>` elements and add the animation-delay to their links.

```css
a {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 200%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1em;
  transform: scale(0);
  animation: scaleIn .5s;
  animation-fill-mode: both
}
li:nth-of-type(even) a {
  animation-delay: 1s
}
li:nth-of-type(odd) a {
  animation-delay: 2s
}
@keyframes scaleIn {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Portfolio</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">About</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I just realized that.. I was applying it to the only link element and had to put it on the LI, thanks man. I feel so stupid cause i've been with CSS since 2008.

Comment: Don't worry. Especially selector logic that is syntactically correct but doesn't give any hints on semantic failures in your IDE can be annoying. Please mark the answer as accepted with the check under the vote button.